# Http Call to Rest WebService through java application

Tags: netty, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been using Apache Http project all this while if any calls have to be made to get data from different application.  Recently i came across http://netty.io project which is alternative to apache http and having used elastic search project which uses netty, i was very impressed with speed.  Is netty a good alternative if i need to make synchronous requests to get data from different application?  Does it have a performance edge over apache http? Or are there any other options apart from apache http and netty for improving the performance of http call through java??

Answer (score 1):

If you are building your own REST API , or are accessing REST API's and have networking requirements that focus on http or ssl protocols ...

GO with Apache.

If you are using other protocols and are apt to be dragged down toward what bytes are  in packets on the wire, and will be using Wireshark to dig into more complex network protocols,  then go with Netty .